# Bootstrap 3 progress bar percentages to be displayed under it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the default bootstrap stacked progress bar. I would like to be able to show the percentages under the progress bar in white space instead of on it.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width:13%">13%</div>
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width:7%">7%</div>
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:80%">80%</div>
                </div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put it in new div, add some styling and you're done. example:

```css
.progress-desc {
  margin-top: -1.5em;
}
.progress-desc div {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width:13%"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width:7%"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:80%"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress-desc">
  <div style="width:13%">13%</div>
  <div style="width:7%">7%</div>
  <div style="width:80%">80%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers! Appreciate it!